# Нагрузка сервера PHP

Tags: php, сервер

Здравствуйте.
Я хотел бы узнать, прибавляет ли какую-нибудь нагрузку на сервер чрезмерное использование кавычек, например, можно написать так:

```
for($j=0;$j<=count($file_content);$j++)
if(isset($file_content[$j]))
fputs($file,$file_content[$j]);
```

а можно и так:

```
for($j=0;$j<=count($file_content);$j++)
{
    if(isset($file_content[$j]))
    {
        fputs($file,$file_content[$j]);
    }
}
```

Прибавляет ли второй код нагрузку на сервер?

Comment: @Asen Уважаемый участник, для форматирования кода достаточно четырех пробелов перед каждой строкой. Знак цитирования не нужен.

Comment: Прошу прощения.

Comment: >чрезмерное использование кавычек

А во втором примере разве кавычки добавились?

Может вы имели в виду отступы? Тогда нет.

Comment: Не в том месте Вы ищите способы снижения нагрузки на сервер) Лишние кавычки по сравнению с медленными алгоритмами это как песчинка на пляже.

Comment: @Construct, кавычки - "{" и "}".

@ReinRaus, я это прекрасно понимаю. У меня сервер не загружен, и я не ищу способы снижения нагрузки. Просто мне хотелось бы уточнить это.

Comment: @Asen, это называется "кавычки"? О_о
Я думал "фигурные скобки".
Кавычки это """

Comment: Ну да, фигурные скобки, ошибочка...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Человек, я так полагаю, имел в виду фигурные скобки. И ответ так же - нет, нагрузки не добавят.

P.S. Кстати, о кавычках. Есть мнение, что одинарные работают быстрее.

Comment: 100% одинарные работают быстрее, т.к. в них тупо текст, не будет подстановки вместо переменных, как в двойных, а ведь чтобы заменить надо анализировать, что, безусловно, дольше и нагруженнее, но это все крайне малые нагрузки, так что можно не париться.

Comment: @butteff, с другой стороны, строк же очень много, да и париться не надо - просто привыкнуть писать одинарные.
Вот вам и профит. Я использую в PHP везде одинарные.

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду фигурные скобки...какие нафиг кавычки.....

Comment: @Construct, одинарные не всегда уместны, так как двойные кавычки использовать удобнее, когда переменные выводятся вперемешку с текстом, но в противном случае можно использовать конкатенацию.

Answer (score 2):

Разницы нет, НО есть такой весьма значимый фактор как ЧИТАБЕЛЬНОСТЬ КОДА, вот его нужно придерживаться и писать { } т.к. это упрощает читабельность кода.

Answer (score -1):

а теперь представьте массив $file_content длиной в миллион элементов и сравните по скорости два примера:

```
for($j=0;$j<=count($file_content);$j++)
{
    if(isset($file_content[$j]))
    {
        fputs($file,$file_content[$j]);
    }
}
```

и так:

```
$c=count($file_content);
for($j=0;$j<=$c;$j++)
{
    if(isset($file_content[$j]))
    {
        fputs($file,$file_content[$j]);
    }
}
```

вы удивитесь :)

Comment: Ну, скобки тут явно ни при чем. Вынесли вызов функции за цикл и чему тут удивляться ? 

Недостаточной изощренности реализации PHP ?

Вызывайте $file_content[$j] один раз перед isset() еще быстрее будет.

Перепишите (с умом) на С и производители железа Вас возненавидят.

Comment: вопрос был связан с нагрузкой на сервер. 
Я считаю, что мое замечание относится к этому.

Comment: Действительно. Человек заморачивается какими-то скобками, а сам грешит постоянным вызовом большого объекта. Видимо пока узнал только про скобки.